# Rails: Model instance method or helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

By convention, should the following be defined as an instance method of my model or a helper method?

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

or

```
# app/helpers/users_helper.rb
module UsersHelper
  def full_name
    "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}"
  end
end
```

Many thanks.

Comment: More general / without code sample version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019794/when-to-use-helpers-vs-model

Comment: The best option is presenter/decorator IMHO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go with the first (keep in model), also because you might want to do other stuff, like combined indexes :)

Answer (score 5):

Everything directly related to your model should stay in your model.

This way, you keep coherent logic and tests.