# How to call Rails' model instance method from the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really new to rails, working on someone else's code, and I'm stuck on the simplest thing!

I defined an instance method in the model but I can't seem to call it. I found a bunch of similar questions but nothing quite right.

For this question, [Rails: Model instance method or helper method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714252/rails-model-instance-method-or-helper-method), how would you then call full_name after defining it in the model? In the rails console `User.first.first_name` returns the first user's first name but `User.first.full_name` returns a undefined method error.

Comment: just do `reload!` in your console and call the method again.

Comment: omg... I knew it had to be something simple like that! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I was doing something exactly like the example in the other question. Arup was right. I reloaded the server but not the console! It's the little things that always trip me up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your were in the rails console before *defining* the method inside the model. That's making the the new method to your model unavailable in the rails *console*. So, just do [`reload!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21)(*reloads the environment*) and try the same again, and this time you will have the access to the method.

Comment: I'd change `#reload!` to `reload!` to avoid confusion of people copy/pasting and not having anything happen.

Comment: @Jon _copy/pasting_ means ? :)

Comment: If someone types `#reload!` in the console, nothing happens, because it is a Ruby comment. You can't have the `#` before it.

Comment: @Jon Humm.. clearly makes sense. I actually write instance methods as `#some_method`.. :) Got into the _habbit_.