# Model or helper? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

We have a model named `Influencer` and a team mate came up with a method for retrieving all emails for a influencer. He then used it in a view. He put it in a helper (module):

```
def emails(influencer)
  # do stuff with influencer to extract emails (spread in several fields)
end
```

I argued that such a method should go into the model, as it can be very useful anywhere in the code apart from the views (we have a very strong job-based backend).

My code inside `Influencer` model will go something like this:

```
def emails
  # do stuff with influencer to extract emails (spread in several fields)
end

influencer.emails # Returns influencer emails.
```

The specific reason he gives is that in the model should only go code that touches the database. IMO anything that abstracts code to retrieve data from the model should go in the model. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714252/rails-model-instance-method-or-helper-method) a question/answer that points out my point of view.

What do you think is the best place to put this method?

Comment: well I would say anything common to object should go into model. But model should be clean and minimal. So finally your method should go into decorators.

Comment: `I argued that such a method should go into the model, as it can be very useful anywhere in the code apart from the views (we have a very strong job-based backend). ` Then it should be in the model as it can be accessible from anywhere in the application.

Comment: My choice is https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving this logic to a separate service, like EmailRetriever. It will have one publeic method `influencer_email(influencer)`. This approach separates logic from both view and model. And you may later add other methods like `doctors_emails(doctor)` etc.