# How to call method from helper in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am working on a financial application. The previous approach used a variety of stored procedures however we have now moved to performing API calls. Originally the code was as follows:

View

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th.year(rowspan=2) Year
      %th.month(rowspan=2) Month
      %th.accounts{colspan: @customer.accounts.size} Accounts
    %tr
      - fetch_cu_accounts(@customer.id).each do |account|
        %th= account.name
  - @today.year.downto(@today.year - 3) do |year|
    %tbody
      - x = (@today.year == year) ? @today.month : 12
      - x.downto(1) do |month|
        %tr
          - if month == x
            %td{rowspan: x}= year
          %td= Date::MONTHNAMES[month]
          /- @customer.accounts.each do |acct|
          - fetch_cu_accounts(@customer.id).each do |acct|
            - if acct.activity[year] && acct.activity[year][month]
              %td{'data-transactions' => acct.activity[year][month]}
                - stmt = acct.statement(year, month)
                = link_to 'View', url(:statements, :show, id: stmt.to_s)
                = link_to image_tag('/icons/document-pdf.png', alt: 'Download PDF'), url(:statements, :show, id: stmt, format: :pdf), class: :pdf
            - else
              %td
```

Model call for activity

```
def activity
  return @activity if @activity

  @activity = {}

  @db.call('IBAccountActivity', @account_id).each do |row|
    @activity[row['year']] = {} unless @activity[row['year']]
    @activity[row['year']][row['month']] = row['transactions']
  end

  @activity
end
```

Controller code:

```
get :show, map: '/accounts/:id' do
  account_number = params[:id].to_i
  @account = @customer.fetch_account(account_number)    
  render 'accounts/show'
end
```

The new approach uses the following:

```
  def get_call(routePath)
    started_at = Time.now
    enc_url = URI.encode("#{settings.abacus_service_endpoint}#{routePath}")
    uri = URI.parse(enc_url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, get_header_for_abacus_service)     
    resp = http.request(req)
    logger.bench 'SERVICE - GET', started_at, routePath
    return resp if response_ok?(resp)
  end
```

The following method will be used:

```
  def activity
    return @activity if @activity

    @activity = {}

    response = get_call('/Accounts/AccountActivity/' + account_id.to_s)
    response = JSON.parse(response.body)

    @activity = response.map do |row|
      @activity[row['year']] = {} unless @activity[row['year']]
      @activity[row['year']][row['month']] = row['transactions']
    end

    @activity
  end
```

At present i get:

```
undefined method activity
```

I want to replace the previous activity method with the following only I wish to have it in my helpers.rb file where the other HTTP call methods currently reside. How can i call this method as at the moment it is not being called.

Comment: What is this `helpers.rb` that you talk about?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev It is the helpers file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019794/when-to-use-helpers-vs-model)

Comment: Rails' view helpers is not the place for such methods. They're for view niceties (currency formatting and such). This API querying is model code, not view code.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev So how would you go about effectively returning the view?